# Dart: const variables must be initialized with a constant value

Tags: dart

Why there is an error, when the `foo` is already a `const` value?

```
const foo = const [10, 20];
const bar = foo[0] * 2; // error: const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because while the variables used to create your second constant are constants, you also used the operator [] – which is not compile-time constant.

So while you can do:

```dart
const a = 42;
const b = a * 3;
```

you cannot do:

```dart
const array = [42];
const b = a[0];
```

Comment: Its giving the same error for `const String name = 1.toString();`? Here **1** is a constant but `dart` is still its generating `Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
Try changing the initializer to be a constant`