# Android Studio: How to update Dart SDK constraints?

Tags: flutter, dart

The screenshot shows a way to do that:

[image]

But even after clicking it multiple times, restarting Android Studio, I am not able to change it. How can I change it?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69908425/11675817

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `pubspec.yaml` file and change it.

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Note: this is performed automatically by the refactoring option.

Comment: @RémiRousselet It should have performed but it didn't. I also restarted AS couple of times, after tapping on the option `Update the SDK constraints`.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Additionally, can you also help me on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373472/dart-const-variables-must-be-initialized-with-a-constant-value)